# jeditable close new when other opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

I am trying to edit jeditable js in order to add some functionality
I have my own onblur() function.
what i want to do is to close new jeditable if already one is opend

my code is :

```
t = setTimeout(function() {
     var focusedElem=$(document.activeElement);
         if(focusedElem.is("textarea"){
        **//what should i write in order to cancel the new one 
             $(e.target).focus(); //return the focus to the old one
         }
         else
             reset.apply(form, [settings, self]);
           }, 500);
```

I am trying to make the code generic and user friendly, thats why i dont want any user that use my plugin to write id for each element. so please dont give answers that use id.

i have tried to write the following raws but any of them is making error
reset.apply(form, [settings, focusedElem]);
reset.apply(form, [settings, $(focusedElem)]);

more than that i don't want to trigger on a cancel button (maybe he is not want to add it(user friendly))

Comment: Could you set a jsfiddle?

Comment: I cannot make, cause i dont know which code to write(but i have tried )
The only thing i can say is that if you look at the plugin source 
you will see "if(settings.onblur=='cancel')"
inside this "if statement" i have written my code .